# eclipse shortcut to call setters of a POJO

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose I have a POJO with 10 fields with setters and getters. If I want to instantiate that class, I have to manually type those setters method.

For E.g.

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setId(XXX);
emp.setName(XXX);
emp.setCompany(XXX);
```

and so on.

Is there a eclipse shortcut to call setters of class?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a constructor to set all the fields: `Employee emp = new Employee(id, name, company, ...);`?

Comment: When a class has more number of variables it is difficult to remember the order of values defined in the constructor.

Comment: @ArjunDoijode why do you want to remember the order of values ? There's no such need.

Comment: @rdj7 When I said order, I was talking about setting values through constructor.

Comment: @ArjunDoijode ohh my bad i thought other way, I hope answer explains what you want.

Comment: why don't you use `ctrl+space`.More Simpler declare method like `getInstance(id,name,company...)`. You can even design custom constructors if you have multiple needs

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have Employee class,

Employee constructor would be like,

```
public Employee(int empId, String empName, String empDept, String address, int pinCode){

//Costructor Body eg. this.empId = empId etc. 

}
```

Instantiation of Employee with constructor would be like,

`Employee e = new Employee(1,"abc","def","ghi",123);`

If you want to instantiate that class without remembering order of variables Then all you have to do is type

`Employee e = new E` Now press `Ctrl + Space` Eclipse will prompt you with all the constructors available for that class for instantiation of Employee object.
With this, You don't need to remember the order in which those variables are given in to constructor as parameters.

Hope this helps !